# Making my countplot brighter(more saturated)

Tags: pandas, seaborn

My count plot look kind of dull, I set theme to darkgrid and it still looked the dull as when it was set to whitegrid. Is there something else I am supposed to add?

```
ax = sns.countplot(y= 'Product line', data= merged)
ax.set_title('Product Line Sales')
plt.ylabel('Product Line')
plt.xlabel('Quantity Sold')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try `sns.countplot(...., saturation=1)`? [The default is `0.75`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html). In seaborn's vision, large colored areas look better when they are less saturated.

Comment: Yes I did, it still didn't make any difference

Comment: Well, the difference isn't extreme. You can try `saturation=1, palette='Set1'` for some more vivid colors.